# Why does my vuetify app lose its styling when I turn it into a web component?

Tags: vuetify.js, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to build a web component using vuetify. However, when I embed that web component in a container, the shadow-dom loses its styling and the result is just a bunch of dull grey buttons.

I've created a simple example of what I am talking about at:

https://github.com/spierepf/vuetify-webcomponent-poc

Comment: please post your code as an SO Snippet with the [<>] button. Links to other places can be gone next week

Comment: This seems to work: https://blog.panda-studio.cn/vue_web_component_webpack_compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veutify add the CSS styling to the top of the document when you use any of its components. So when your component gets wrapped inside a custom element within Shadow DOM, then all the styling provided by `Veutify` is not accessible inside shadow DOM.

There are two options you can try:

1. Use custom elements without shadow DOM
2. Try to inject Veutify inside shadow DOM using [constructible stylesheets](https://blog.webf.zone/on-styling-web-components-b74b8c70c492).

Comment: "Try to inject Veutify inside shadow DOM using constructible stylesheets"
 Do you any example pelase for vuetify with vue

Comment: @karlos Get the compiled CSS of Veutify file as string file using Webpack's `raw-loader` and then pass that string to constructible stylesheet constructor.

Comment: thanks. Can we have an article like CSSOM  taht show the steps please. its really à big problem with vuetify that exist sinc long time ago.

Comment: Any solution to add external css in shadow dom? I'm using the third party plugin and converting into web component

Comment: @HarshalPatil, I've the same problem, but i didn't understand how can include vuetify options like theme throught the approach you've explained!.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for vuetify 3: https://blog.panda-studio.cn/vue_web_component_webpack_compiler

```
import LayoutVue from './layouts/LayoutVue.vue';
import { nextTick, createApp } from 'vue';

const myCustomLightTheme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: colors,
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components: {
        VLayout,
        VAppBar,
        VNavigationDrawer,
        VMain,
        VContainer,
        VList,
        VListItem,
        // core journal components end
    },
    directives: {
        // resize,
    },
    icons: {
        defaultSet: 'fa',
        aliases,
        sets: {
            fa,
        },
    },
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'myCustomLightTheme',
        themes: {
            myCustomLightTheme,
        },
    },
})

customElements.define('layout-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        nextTick(() => {
            var block_data = this.data || {};
            var app = createApp(LayoutVue, {
                data: block_data,
            }).mount(this);

            app.use(vuetify);
        })
    }
})
```